# How do i transfer 20 .html files from Linux to Windows in a single csh/perl/python script?

Tags: html, c, linux, perl, shell

I am working on getting multiple .html files from Linux environment to Windows. For now, the easiest way that I've been using is uuencode command.

However, since I have 20 .html files, I used two .csh files as only 10 files can run at a time. If I combine all 20.html files, it will return error: Too many arguments. This may be due to the long directories of each .html files.

For example, this is the uuencode commands that I used in Lintowin.csh for 10 .html files:

```
(uuencode /main/fileno/no1/user/username/mainproject/projectname/division/parts/sub/16_april/fullreport/part_report/report_A/output_A/summary.html A.xls;uuencode /main/fileno/no1/user/username/mainproject/projectname/division/parts/sub/16_april/fullreport/part_report/report_B/output_B/summary.html B.xls;uuencode /main/fileno/no1/user/username/mainproject/projectname/division/parts/sub/16_april/fullreport/part_report/report_C/output_C/summary.html C.xls;uuencode /main/fileno/no1/user/username/mainproject/projectname/division/parts/sub/16_april/fullreport/part_report/report_D/output_D/summary.html D.xls;uuencode /main/fileno/no1/user/username/mainproject/projectname/division/parts/sub/16_april/fullreport/part_report/report_E/output_E/summary.html E.xls;uuencode /main/fileno/no1/user/username/mainproject/projectname/division/parts/sub/16_april/fullreport/part_report/report_F/output_F/summary.html F.xls;uuencode /main/fileno/no1/user/username/mainproject/projectname/division/parts/sub/16_april/fullreport/part_report/report_G/output_G/summary.html G.xls;uuencode /main/fileno/no1/user/username/mainproject/projectname/division/parts/sub/16_april/fullreport/part_report/report_H/output_H/summary.html H.xls;uuencode /main/fileno/no1/user/username/mainproject/projectname/division/parts/sub/16_april/fullreport/part_report/report_I/output_I/summary.html I.xls;uuencode /main/fileno/no1/user/username/mainproject/projectname/division/parts/sub/16_april/fullreport/part_report/report_J/output_J/summary.html J.xls) | \mail -s "attachmentname" email@yahoo.com
```

The format is 
(uuencode file_path file_format_in_Windows) | \mail -s "attachment name" receiver_email

Is there any way on how I can fix this and make it more simpler since I need to automate this action. Is there any way I can use perl script or other command so that i can transfer all 20 .html files at a time?

Comment: That depends on how you want to transfer. Given like this, a simple ZIP archive seems to do the job in a pretty portable way.

Comment: does it means that zip all the 20 files, then send it through email?

Comment: Or whatever other exchange means you have. With no more information on your environment it's hard to tell. You could push it to an SMB share, upload it through FTP, pipe it through the network... For all we know you could be talking about the to OS on the same system so you could just copy over the zip file to a common partition before rebooting.

Answer (score 0):

Stick 'tar' in front:

```
tar cvfz - ./path_to_files | uuencode stuff.tar.gz | mail -s "attachmentname" email@yahoo.com
```

`-` 'prints' the `tar` to STDOUT and thus fed into uuencode. And gzips it, which might save some space. (You could probably use `zip` instead I'd imagine if zip files are easier to handle)

Answer (score -2):

You can use smtp library in python and send an email with multiple attachments. All you have to do is get all your files into your python script by using directory modules and then simply send an email.

Here is a link to the tutorial on how to send emails using python:

http://naelshiab.com/tutorial-send-email-python/